# VS2008 Load Testing Error (LoadTest Database)

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, testing, load

I have the LoadTest database setup on my machine. I can connect to it from my development box.  No problems there.

When I go to TEST -> Administer Test Controllers and test my connection, it succeeds. I have the LoadTest db on my server and it does connect with Windows Authentication.

However, when running the load test I created, I get the following error:

'The load test results database could not be opened. Check that the load test results database specified by the connect string for your Test Controller (or local machine) specifies a database that contains the load test schema and that is currently available. For more information, see the Visual Studio Team System help topc 'About the Load Test Results Store'. The connection error was: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

What the heck, may I ask, is the deal here?

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI for everyone -- Must have an instance of SQL Server that is NOT the Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. But i had made the following changes and its start working.

1. The mistake which i had make was the test controller machine name and SQL Server test machine name was different. I had make the changes in load test and make the names same.
2. connect the sql server and enable its connection.
3. Un-check all the Data and Diagnostics options which is in Test-> Edit test setting-> Local setting-> data and Diagnostics-> Uncheck all the check boxes and save it.
4. Use Local Test Setting for running the load test.